# JavaScript: bind an object's method to event handler

Tags: javascript, event-handling

According to John Resig's 'Learning Advanced JavaScript' (http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#83) it's incorrect to bind an object's method to event handler without passing the original object as context, however I find the example flawed. It claims the clicked property gets set accidentally. Here's a counter-example.

```
var Button = {
  click: function(){
    this.clicked = true;
    console.log( elem.clicked );
  }
};

var elem = document.createElement("li");
elem.innerHTML = "Click me!";
elem.onclick = Button.click;
document.children[0].appendChild(elem);

console.log( !elem.clicked );
```

There must be another reason not to do this. What is it?

Comment: What do you mean? That code *will* set the "clicked" property of the `<li>`.

Comment: Also you skipped the very important line of code in that example, where the "click" event was actually triggered. In your code above, the "click" function will never even be called.

Comment: it's not "wrong" if it works, it's just potentially confusing to other coders...

Answer (score 9):

In any object method, `this` always refers to the object the method *has been called on*. It's true for all JavaScript that `this` provides the *calling context*, not the *method owner* <sup>(*)</sup>.

```
var sample = {
    foo: function () {
        this.clicked = true;
    }
}

sample.foo();         // 'this' refers to 'sample' 
alert(sample.clicked) // true
```

In an event handler `this` refers to the element that triggered the event. This means when you pass an object method to the `click` event...

```
var div = document.getElementById("test");
div.onclick = sample.foo;
```

then `foo()` will be *called on* the DOM element, even though it has been defined elsewhere.

```
/* ... click the div ... */ 

alert(sample.clicked); // false
alert(div.clicked);    // true
```

which will lead to unexpected results.

---

<sup>(*)</sup> That's because technically there is no method owner in JavaScript. Methods are standalone functions that happen to be referenced by object properties. Storing a reference to the same function in a different object (`div.onclick = sample.foo` does just that) is easily possible.

Consequently, `obj.method()` is syntactic sugar.

```
function func() { /* ... */ }
var obj = {
    method: func
};

obj.method();
func.call(obj);  // same thing
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to get around this

```
elem.onclick = Button.click.bind(Button);
```

---

**Note** `.bind` requires ECMAScript `>= 5`

Answer (score 2):

What Mr. Resig is talking about is the fact that in JavaScript, `this` gets a value in a way that's distinctly different from how `this` works in some other languages.  In this example, I think his point is that the reference to `this` in the "click" function on that "Button" object doesn't necessarily refer to that object. Instead, its value is determined only by the situation in which the function is called.

Thus, when you use that function as an event handler, the value of `this` in the function will be a reference to the element that was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example, without events.

```
var foo = {
  method: function() {
    this.prop = true;
  }
};

var bar = {};

bar.method = foo.method;
bar.method();

console.log( foo.prop ); // => undefined
console.log( bar.prop ); // => true

foo.method();

console.log( foo.prop ); // => true
```

It seems like in your example, you're checking the state of `elem.clicked` *before* clicking the element. Click it, and the property will get set (but `Button.clicked` won't be set!). The correct way to do this is simply:

```
elem.onclick = function() { Button.click(); };
```