# Calling onclick prototype function

Tags: javascript, dom

Hello I have a function

```
Fortune.prototype.entername = function () {
    var person = prompt("Please enter your name", "Harry Potter");
    if (person != null) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
        "Hello " + person + "! Check Your Fortune";
    };
    this.words();
}
```

I want to call it using button 
here is my code `<p  class="dark" id="demo"><button onclick="this.entername()">Click to Enter Name & see your Fortune</button></p>`

However it says `this.entername()` is not a function. Silly mistake I dont know how to call it full js code is here https://jsfiddle.net/e9zywrnt/

Comment: What do you think  `this` is in the scope of an event handler attribute?

Comment: @Bergi I get error this.entername is not a function. I dont really know because in this case I am using .prototype in function. Before I just used to enter function name

Comment: What do you mean by before? It is really unclear how you expect an event handler on a DOM element to access your `Fortune` instance.

Comment: @Bergi I just want the Fortune.prototype.entername fnction to run when button is clicked

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: bind an object's method to event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20586072/javascript-bind-an-objects-method-to-event-handler)

Comment: Then use `onclick="Fortune.prototype.entername()"`. But why are you trying to make that a method at all? What should the `this` instance inside it represent, what should `this.words()` do?

Comment: @Bergi It runs now this.words() is another function which also is triggered.

Comment: Still you should not use prototype methods at all if you don't have multiple objects that would use them. Your previous code with a plain function was just fine.