# Clear text only when the outer dom contains text and another dom

Tags: javascript, html

```
  <td  id="gender3" name ="gender">Male
      <input id = "gender_input3" type="text" style="border:ridge;width:90px; display: none" name="gender" >      
  </td>
```

A **td** contains text and another dom called input.
When certain action is triggered, I only want to clear the text.

```
td  = document.getElementById("gender3")
td.innerText = ""
```

This will also eliminate input tag.

How can I do? Thanks.

Comment: Bind that action to event listener, and whenever that even is triggered, you can clear the text.  Something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20586072/javascript-bind-an-objects-method-to-event-handler

Comment: Which one you wish to clear: The "Male" word or the text inside the input box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `innerText` to find `Male` text, and use `replace` (or `replaceAll`) on `innerHTML` which will remove text only

```js
const td = document.getElementById("gender3")
td.innerHTML = td.innerHTML.replace(td.innerText.trim(), "")
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="gender3" name="gender">Male
      <input id="gender_input3" type="text" style="border:ridge;width:90px" name="gender" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

*Side note that I removed `display: none` on the input element for testing purpose.*

Answer (score 1):

If you need to remove nodes being of type text, you can fetch the input parent node (the td element) using the `#gender3` selector and list all of its child nodes, removing only nodes being of that type (where `.nodeType` is 3).

This is a demo that accomplishes that by adding a click event listener to the trigger button that when fired will perform the action described above:

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('action');
btn.addEventListener('click', (event)=>{
  const inputParent = document.getElementById('gender3');  
  //removes all child nodes having nodeType being a text node
  inputParent.childNodes.forEach((o,i)=>{
    if (o.nodeType == 3)
      o.remove();
  });    
});
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
      <td id="gender3" name="gender">
        Male
        <input type="text" id="gender_input3" name="gender"> 
      </td>  
    </tr>
 </table>
 
 <button id="action" type="button">Event triggering the change</button>
```

For the sake of records it would be more appropriate to use a label element instead (bound to the input control) and just select such element and change its text.